# Outboud connection to external mysql server times out

Tags: iptables

I'm attempting to connect to an external mysql host (11.22.33.44), but the connection continues to time out. The server I'm connecting from (55.66.77.88) is up and has internet connectivity.

Server 55.66.77.88 iptables config is presently:

```
# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I've tried using `telnet 11.22.33.44 3306` but this also times out.

Server 11.22.33.44's firewalld config:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=drop
drop (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 55.66.77.88/32
  services: http https mountd nfs ntp rpc-bind smtp ssh
  ports: 3306/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule family="ipv4" source address="55.66.77.88" service name="mysql" accept
```

What am I overlooking? I am able to establish a telnet connection to 11.22.33.44 from my laptop.

Comment: Have you verified that iptables is the problem?  Does temporarily disabling the firewall allow you to connect?

Comment: disabled iptables service, still getting timeouts.  I recently added a rule to iptables on the connecting server 55.66.77.88. That's when this started. I've since reset iptables config to defaults and now disabled iptables. I'm at a loss now.  No changes were made to the remote server 11.22.33.44 (I'm the only one with direct access).

Comment: When you try to access the remote server from the command line, what error do you get?

Comment: I'm able to ssh to the remote server from my laptop no problem. I could do the same from server 55.66.77.88 if I took the time to set up passwordless login.

Comment: Not ssh.  I meant use `mysql -u 'a coder' -h 11.22.33.44 -p`.  It should connect on port 3306.

Comment: $ mysql -udbuser -p -h11.22.33.44
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '11.22.33.44' (110)